# android database: how to properly extracting data from database?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am working on saving and extracting data to and from database, with the key being the day selected from the Calendar.

It is a kind of recording weight data for each day. If I have input the required data to Day A, and then I go on extract data for Day A, everything is fine.

## My question:

If I have NOT input anything for Day A and directly go on extracting data for Day A, it will crash. How could I modify the codes such that users can safely getting a Toast saying "User has not input record for this day, no record found" if no record in DB?

## Codes:

```
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();   
    try
    {
         new LoadDataTask().execute(record_day_int);
    }
    catch (SQLiteException e)
    {
        System.err.println("Exception Message: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

   private class LoadDataTask extends AsyncTask<Long, Object, Cursor> 
   {
       DataBaseHelper databaseConnector = new DataBaseHelper(Calendar_view.this);

      @Override
      protected Cursor doInBackground(Long... params)
      {
         databaseConnector.open();
         return databaseConnector.getOneRecord(params[0]);
      } 

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result)
      {
         super.onPostExecute(result);

         result.moveToFirst();

         int weight_kg01Index = result.getColumnIndex("weight_kg01");
             weight_data.setText(""+result.getInt(weight_kg01Index));

         result.close();
         databaseConnector.close();
      }
   }
```

## Logcat:

```
08-28 01:06:16.790: W/dalvikvm(19928): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x412282a0)
08-28 01:06:16.790: E/AndroidRuntime(19928): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-28 01:06:16.790: E/AndroidRuntime(19928): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
08-28 01:06:16.790: E/AndroidRuntime(19928):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:418)
08-28 01:06:16.790: E/AndroidRuntime(19928):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
08-28 01:06:16.790: E/AndroidRuntime(19928):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getInt(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:68)
08-28 01:06:16.790: E/AndroidRuntime(19928):    at com.abc.abc.Calendar_view$LoadContactTask.onPostExecute(Calendar_view.java:233)
08-28 01:06:16.790: E/AndroidRuntime(19928):    at com.abc.abc.Calendar_view$LoadContactTask.onPostExecute(Calendar_view.java:1)
08-28 01:06:16.790: E/AndroidRuntime(19928):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
08-28 01:06:16.790: E/AndroidRuntime(19928):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
08-28 01:06:16.790: E/AndroidRuntime(19928):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
08-28 01:06:16.790: E/AndroidRuntime(19928):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-28 01:06:16.790: E/AndroidRuntime(19928):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-28 01:06:16.790: E/AndroidRuntime(19928):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
08-28 01:06:16.790: E/AndroidRuntime(19928):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-28 01:06:16.790: E/AndroidRuntime(19928):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-28 01:06:16.790: E/AndroidRuntime(19928):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
08-28 01:06:16.790: E/AndroidRuntime(19928):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
08-28 01:06:16.790: E/AndroidRuntime(19928):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do

```
if(result.moveToFirst()){
    int weight_kg01Index = result.getColumnIndex("weight_kg01");
         weight_data.setText(""+result.getInt(weight_kg01Index));
}
result.close();
```

that way if the cursor is empty then it will skip that

Comment: Also worth checking the `Cursor` is not null. For example `if (result != null && result.moveToFirst()) {...}`

Comment: @Squonk cursor should never be null

Comment: @tyczj : The OP is calling a method on an instance of his/her `DataBaseHelper` class. It is entirely possible that the `Cursor` which is returned might actually be null if (for some reason) the query fails and the `Cursor` hasn't been initialized. Without seeing the code for the helper, it is impossible to say whether the `Cursor` could ever be null or not.